# Perpetual motion in Nil-geometry?

Tags: curvature, geometry, topology, perpetual-motion

By the [Geometrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture), there are 8 "fundamental" geometries a 3D manifold can take-up (up to isomorphism). 5 of which ($R^3$, $H^3$, $S^3$, $S^2\times R$, and $H^2\times R$), I can reasonably imagine physics behaving relatively expectantly, as the only variate between these is curvature, which our laws of physics can certainly adapt to. But for the remaining three, $\text{Nil, Sol, and } \widetilde{SL}(2,R)$, I lack intuition.

According to my (relatively new) understanding from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNX1rZotjjI&ab_channel=ZenoRogue), the classic Escherian [Penrose stairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_stairs) can faithfully exist in $\text{Nil}$ geometry. This immediately made me wonder if it were possible for a ball, or some other object, to descend forever in such a universe, or if other perpetual motion was possible.

Of course, I imagine that this depends on what laws we assume still apply here, as presumably many of our laws posit a Euclidian / spherical / hyperbolic geometry of this universe, right?

> In the case that we can make sense of physics in Nil geometry, is there an explanation for the behavior of a ball dropped down a Penrose staircase? Does it require energy to descend such a staircase, or will the ball roll forever? And if it does, will it continue to gain (kinetic) energy?